# nginx: Trouble after upgrade to newer version

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have upgraded my nginx server from 1.1.19 to 1.8.0 using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10).

My website is still working. So I thought, that everything was ok. I have made a google pagespeed test, and showed me that gzip was't on. But it was on.

I tried to reload nginx with this command **sudo service nginx reload** but got this message

```
reload: not running
```

Stop nginx seems also not to work.

What does this mean, what do I have to check or to change?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

As @ahmed-i suggested here is the output of **ps -ef|grep nginx**:

```
www-data 15782     1  0 May11 ?        00:00:51 nginx: worker process
www-data 15783     1  0 May11 ?        00:00:56 nginx: worker process
www-data 15784     1  0 May11 ?        00:00:55 nginx: worker process
root     25396 23725  0 13:36 pts/1    00:00:00 nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.1.1.19.backup

root     30204 25115  0 14:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that latest Nginx might have been installed on some other location.

paste the output of below command

ps -ef|grep nginx

Comment: I'have updated the question.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: from that command output it seems like nginx master process is already died but chile processes are running. Just kill those processes (15783,15784,15782) and then restart nginx once

Comment: I have restarted the ubuntu server, but the problem is still there